# Como adicionar chamar uma classe de conexão dentro de uma classe de consulta

Tags: php, funções, pdo, classes, conexão

Aprendi na faculdade apenas essa maneira de conexão e consulta com o banco, tendo a função de consulta dentro da classe de conexão, mas não estou gostando, pois comecei um projeto grande e fica muito confuso.
Queria saber se da pra deixar uma classe apenas com a conexão, e nas outras eu crio a função e faço a referência a conexão de alguma maneira.

```
class quiosque{
    private $host = "host.com.br";
    private $database = "db";
    private $user = "user";
    private $password = "senha";
    private $conexao = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->conecta();
    }
    public function conecta()
    {
        try {
            $this->conexao = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;
            dbname=$this->database", "$this->user", "$this->password");
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            echo "Não foi possível estabelecer a conexão 
            com o banco de dados: Erro" . $e->getCode();
        }
    }

    public function readLocal()
    {
        $sql = 
        " SELECT 
            l.id
            ,l.local_origem
        from local l
        left join tipo_local t on t.id = l.id_tipo_local

        where t.id = 2
        order by 1
        ";

        $statement = $this->conexao->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute();
        $array = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $array;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá, Lucas.

Acredito que essa solução deixa seu código mais limpo e mais legível até mesmo para manutenções futuras.

Você pode criar um arquivo a parte para a sua classe de banco de dados. Por exemplo:

Você poder criar um arquivo como:
**conexao_bd.php**

```
<?php
class conexaoDB
{

    public static $pdo;
    public $hostname;
    public $database;
    public $usuario;
    public $senha;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->hostname = 'ip do seu servidor';
        $this->database = 'a base de dados a ser utilizada';
        $this->usuario = 'o usuário a ser utilizado na conexão';
        $this->senha = 'a senha do usuário utilizado';
                
    }

    public function conectaDB()
    {
        try {
            if (!static::$pdo) {
                $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->hostname . ';dbname=' . $this->database;
                $opcoes = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8");
                static::$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->usuario, $this->senha, $opcoes);
            }
            return static::$pdo;
        } catch (PDOException $erro) {
            die("Erro ao conectar ao banco " . $erro->getMessage());
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Nas classe que farão uso da conexão, você pode chamar a sua classe da seguinte forma (no meu caso é o arquivo **listaPessaos.php**):

```
<?php

class listaPessoas
{
    private $bd;

    public function __construct(){
        require_once('./class/conexao_bd.php');
        $this->bd = new conexaoDB();
    }

    public function buscaPessoasBD()
    {
        $stmt = $this->bd->conectaDB()->prepare("sua query");
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($stmt->rowCount() >= 1) {
            return $stmt;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

Você pode notar que no arquivo listaPessoas.php, eu dou um require no meu arquivo conexao_bd.php que contém a minha classe de conexão com o banco de dados e posteriormente estancio a classe (conexaoDB()) e posteriormente passo ela para uma variável:

```
public function __construct(){
    require_once('./class/conexao_bd.php');
    $this->bd = new conexaoDB();
}
```

E depois chamo o método (conectaDB()) que realiza a minha query:

```
<?php
 $stmt = $this->bd->conectaDB()->prepare("sua query");
?>
```

Caso algo tenha ficado confuso de ser entendido, me informe o que você não conseguiu compreender que tentarei explicar de outra forma.

Um abraço.

Comment: Cara, perfeito, é isso aí mesmo, vai ficar muito mais limpo. Vou refatorar o projeto, muito obrigado!